# Backbone render external template without $.get

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, asynchronous

I have a little bug into my app.

Is a problem of rendering when I load an external template.

I have a file js with my backbone app and a separate html file for the template.

I need to make the loop function inside my app.

This is my render function:

```
_.each(here.data_table.models, function(t) {
   $.get('js/template.html', function (data) {
         template = _.template(data, {data: t});//Option to pass any dynamic values to template
         $(here.el).find('tbody').append(template);
    }, 'html');
});
```

If I print `here.data_table.models` I can see all my collection in the correct order.

But when I print the order isn't that, is random.

So the problem I think is the `$.get`  call because is asynchronous.

Does exist a way to make the same things in synchronous mode to load in the original order my data?

Example:

this is my `here.data_table.models` simplified if I print attributes order:

```
1
2
3
4
```

If I put a console.log inside my $.get function I can get this:

```
3
2
4
1
```

Another order not the originale because is async.

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: What I normally do is put these kind of calls in my Router, before handing off to the View. Just View Should Really™ (as a "best practice"), not really do much other than render itself. So I would hand it all the data it needs before instantiating it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that there is no guaranteed order for when AJAX calls will complete. However, you only need one AJAX call since your `$.get` fetches the same template over and over. That means that you can turn your code inside out:

```
$.get('js/template.html', function(t) {
  var template = _.template(t); // Just compile it once.
  _.each(here.data_table.models, function(model) {
    $(here.el).find('tbody').append(template({ data: model }));
  });
}, 'html');
```

I've renamed a few variables along the way to make the names better match their functions.

Also, if `here` is a view instance then you could say:

```
here.$('tbody').append(...)
```

or

```
var template = _.template(t);
var $tbody   = here.$('tbody');
_.each(here.data_table.models, function(model) {
  $tbody.append(...);
});
```

instead of the wasteful:

```
$(here.el).find('tbody').append(...)
```